# Is there a rendering problem with the camera in blender 2.9?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have rendered before and have noticed a weird artefact issue in 2.9 that appears in the camera view and sometimes when meshes interact.  Is this a known issue and is it solvable or do I have to go back to 2.83/2?  I assume my project is not going to go much better.

[image: not camera view]

[image: camera view]

I rendered an earlier image with the same settings and it was fine, but when these artefacts appeared I rendered and it shut down my R5-graphics with an error and I had to turn off the computer and reload again.

The clipping is unlikely to be an issue if the item is closer than the rendered rock and sun in the background on the full image that is bigger.  This is just the centre of the work area.

Sometimes I have had this where if I move the objects imported on another project, then I get similar artefacts until I move them, but move them again and they come back even in different positions.

Comment: Have you checked that the clipping values for the viewport are in an appropriate range? If this is a bug, the missing icon to switch between orthographic and perspective could be related. Have you checked if Blender prints any error messages to the terminal?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your GPU/graphics driver then (and/or a bug in Blender affecting this hardware), would've been interesting to know the error message. Have you tried updating the graphics driver? Please tag users in a comment when adding details, we don't get automatically notified when you edit your question.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I am using linux mint, as far as I know all drivers are updated automatically with the linux updates unless i'm wrong.  I will check.

Comment: That is true. You may also want to check that your AMD Radeon R5 (??) is fulfilling the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.90. GCN first generation or later is required. If it is below the minimum requirements graphics glitches or even crashes may occur.

Comment: Note: A bug in Blender should at most crash the application not the OS. When that happens the bug is most likely in the graphics driver.